Confused about ubuntu serucrity updates
I became aware of the CVE https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-26691. There I saw that a patched version was listed for the OS (focal) I was using.
The fixed package should be "2.4.41-4ubuntu3.3" for 20.04 LTS focal.
Down to the shell, I do not see this version.
apache2:
  Installiert:           2.4.41-4ubuntu3.21
  Installationskandidat: 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.21
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.21 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.41-4ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

In order to get the latest infos I deleted the local apt cache and rebuilt the cache again. But without any changes.
What can I do to update to version 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.3?

Shouldn't 3.21 be newer than 3.3?

You nailed it - I didnt ‍️ thanks man

@Ray, If you write up an answer (even with same detail as I used) & I'll delete what I just wrote...  (other than links; it's pretty much what you said in your prior comment!)

@guiverc Thanks a lot for the offer, but I'm not after points here.  :-) Just wanted to help others.  And I didn't have time 2 hours ago to write more than that one line.  Thanks for doing it; all looks good!

The package you have installed contains the patch you're after.
If you scroll down the package changelog of what you have installed; you'll see (down the list)
apache2 (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.3) focal-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: mod_proxy_http denial of service.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2020-13950.patch: don't dereference NULL proxy
      connection in modules/proxy/mod_proxy_http.c.
    - CVE-2020-13950
  * SECURITY UPDATE: stack overflow via Digest nonce in mod_auth_digest
    - debian/patches/CVE-2020-35452.patch: fast validation of the nonce's
      base64 to fail early if the format can't match anyway in
      modules/aaa/mod_auth_digest.c.
    - CVE-2020-35452
  * SECURITY UPDATE: DoS via cookie header in mod_session
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-26690.patch: save one apr_strtok() in
      session_identity_decode() in modules/session/mod_session.c.
    - CVE-2021-26690
  * SECURITY UPDATE: heap overflow via SessionHeader
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-26691.patch: account for the '&' in
      identity_concat() in modules/session/mod_session.c.
    - CVE-2021-26691
  * SECURITY UPDATE: Unexpected matching behavior with 'MergeSlashes OFF'
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-30641.patch: change default behavior in
      server/request.c.
    - CVE-2021-30641
  * This update does _not_ include the changes from 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.2 in
    focal-proposed.

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Thu, 17 Jun 2021 14:27:53 -0400

https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.21/changelog
which is included in the current package
 apache2 | 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.21              | focal-security   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x

As .21 is the 21st change, being far more than .3 or 3rd change (ie. the point number is NOT a decimal).
